# running migrating files inside docker container laravel mysql

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a mysql service as a docker container.

Here's the config at `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel



php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel
```

And `.env` file inside laravel app:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

I can connect to container's mysql from my host:

```
mysql -uhomestead -p -h localhost -P 3307
```

and there are `information_schema` and `homestead` databases listed on `show databases;`

But when I try to run `artisan migrate` command, I get
[image]

I cannot seem to locate the issue, since I've been following [this](https://dev.to/aschmelyun/the-beauty-of-docker-for-local-laravel-development-13c0) tutorial.

Comment: Could you show the compose section of Laravel container?

Comment: @JanshairKhan yes.. I have updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are connecting to MySQL from `Nginx` via the `External (host) Port`. Edit the `.env` file as:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

And add `.env` below in the Nginx service of the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    env_file:
     - ./.env
    networks:
      - laravel
...
```

Make sure `.env` file is at the directory where `docker-compose.yml` is and try again. It should work.

Comment: thanks.. how silly of me to use `3307` inside `.env`. :)
I didn't have to add `.env` to `nginx` service though. What does it do and why is it necessary?

Comment: It is okay if you don't add `.env` to the `nginx` service. `docker-compose` will pick it up by default. This is used when you have a number of environment variables to be used in various services of the `docker-compose` rather than replicating them in each service and making `docker-compose` difficult to read & manage.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself unable to run php artisan commands which require database connection after changing "DB_HOST=localhost" to "DB_HOST=mysql".

commands such as:

- php artisan migrate
- php artisan db:seed

**Solution:**

Add the following to your hosts file: 127.0.0.1 [name_of_container]

Name of container in your case is: mysql